# How to config solr that use Synonym base on KeywordTokenizerFactory

Tags: solr

synonym eg: "AAA" => "AVANT AT ALJUNIED"

If i search AAA*BBB

I can get AVANT AT ALJUNIEDBBB.

I was used StandardTokenizerFactory.But it's always breaking field data into lexical units,and then ignore relative position for search words.

On other way,I try to use StandardTokenizerFactory or other filter like WordDelimiterFilterFactory to split word via * . It don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can't - synonyms works with tokens, and KeywordTokenizer keeps the whole string as a single token. So you can't expand just one part of the string when indexing if you're using KT.

In addition the SynonymFilter isn't MultiTermAware, so it's not invoked on query time when doing a wildcard search - so you can't expand synonyms for parts of the string there, regardless of which tokenizer you're using.

This is probably a good case for preprocessing the string and doing the replacements before sending it to Solr, or if the number of replacements are small, having filters to do pattern replacements inside of the strings when indexing to have both versions indexed.

Comment: Thanks,  but how to split word via *? i try to use StandardTokenizerFactory or other filter like WordDelimiterFilterFactory. it don't work

Comment: If you want to split a token by `*` and neither of those work (.. they should - have you check what's actually happening with either the analysis page or debugQuery appended to your query?) My guess is that you're _actually_ doing a wildcard query, and not a regular query when you include `*` - and that has a set of limitations in how the query is parsed and filtered further.

Comment: In debugQuery , I search AAA*BBB and always see it ,only change to AAA BBB when i use PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory replace * to space, but it's a unit still. when i search AAA\*BBB,it's work .But I can't modify search word . Beacuse other field alse use this one

Comment: If you're replacing `*` with space, you probably want to use a different tokenizer than KeywordTokenizer, so that you actually get separate tokens and can do replacement on each of them (i.e. AAA => ..)